# Java - divide Hashtable into lists

Tags: java, xml, list, arraylist, hashtable

I have for example these pairs:

```
key => name:

"name" => "myname1"
"height" => "myheight1"
"name" => "myname2"
"height" => "myheight2"
```

Now if I put all of these into Hashtable, then second `name` and `height` keys, will overwrite first key `name` and `height` key names. I could add it into two different Hashtables, but before runtime, I don't know how many such pairs will be, so I would not know the number Hashtables I would need. So How Can I add these paris into the lists (without knowing before runtime exact number of such pairs (for example some times there could be three names keys and two height keys with their values etc.).

So when I add all these values, I need in a list to appear like this:

```
list<list<Object>> = [[{name=myname1, height=myheight1}], [{name=myname2, height=myheight2}]]
```

And for example if there would be different number of such pairs like two name and three height pairs:

```
list<list<Object>> = [[{name=myname1, height=myheight1}], [{name=myname2, height=myheight2}], [{height=myheight3}]]
```

**Note:** I get these pairs from xml file, so they are somewhat grouped, like every iteration I get one group of such pairs. For example

```
<main>
  <group>
    <name>myname1</name>
    <height>myheight1</height>
  </group>
  <group>
    <name>myname2</name>
    <height>myheight2</height>    
  </group>
</main>
```

So how could I properly add such pairs into list, so keys would not overwrite each other and later I could get any pair I want from the list?

Comment: Consider using `List<Map<String,String>>`.

Comment: Consider using a `List<Group>`, where Group is a class with a name attribute and a height attribute. Java is an OO language. Define and use your own classes.

Comment: or a `Map<String,List<String>>`

Comment: @McDowell Ok, I would use Map in a List, then what keys I would need to use? As now I don't see any. Or you would just suggest to generate keys on iteration, like first iteration key is one, second is two etc?

Comment: @Andrius the keys would be the localNames of the elements (name, height, etc.) Each map represents a group. There are a list of groups.

Comment: @McDowell But then I would need to create maps depending on group number? So I would need to do it with reflection I suppose as before runtime I would not know how many maps I would need.

Comment: I tried to clone Hashtable in every iteration. So then I would add it's clone into list, it would beautifully fit like I described I would want. But I read that clone is expensive and is broken in Java? So is it bad to use cloning in this case?

Answer (score 3):

Why not just use a List:

```
List<Group> groups = new ArrayList<Group>();
```

where `Group` is defined as

```
public class Group {
    private final String name;
    private final int height;

    public Group(String name, int height) {
        this.name = name;
        this.height = height;
    }

    // getters are left as an exercise to the reader
}
```

(you may need to use another type than int depending on the representation of height).

**EDIT**

Another option would be to use a dynamic language such as Groovy which make such tasks much easier (as you don't have to keep track of your XML document structure). Here's an example:

http://groovyconsole.appspot.com/edit/1445001

Comment: What if later I would get xml, where there would be third different pair, like `weight => value`? I suppose class Group would need to be updated every time if that would happen?

Comment: Yes, just as the rest of your program, in order to use this new information. But at least, everything would be type-safe, and properly encapsulated.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, you can use a `Map<String,List<String>>` (or a `Set` for the second parameter, if you don't care about order).

More specifically, if your data is structured, so should your code and classes be. In this case, consider creating a `Group` class to keep your (semi-)structured data:

```
public class Group {
    String name , height;
    // constructor, getters, setters
}
```

and stuff objects into a `List<Group>` (or `Set` as per above). To retrieve the pairs, you would just iterate over the `List`:

```
List<Group> groups = ....
for ( Group g : groups ) {
    System.out.println( "name=>" + g.getName() + ", height=>" + g.getHeight() );
}
```

Cheers,

Comment: If I would stuff it into created class. How can I easily take pairs like name=>value, height=>value from it? As I would need them to be used elsewhere.

Comment: All the `Group`'s _would be_ your pairs. The getters for `name` and `height` would return the values.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer to go with new class say

```
Class Entry
{
  String name;
  String height
}
```

And now add entries to  `List<Entry>`

Answer (score 0):

As some other answers have said, you probably need to have your 'value' type as a List.

```
class MyClass {
    ....    
    Map<String, List<String>> myMap = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
    ....
    public void addPair(final String key, final String value) {
        if (myMap.containsKey(key)) {
            myMap.get(key).add(value);
        } else {
            final List<String> newList = new ArrayList<String>();
            newList.add(value);
            myMap.put(key, newList);
        }
    }
```

}

Comment: In this solution you lose any relationship between name and height. This is unlikely to be what the poster ultimately wants even though he hasn't expressed this wish.

Comment: Yes, of course I need to keep relationship between keys and values and then between groups or those pairs